# What is the difference between Bare and ExpoKit while ejecting React Native Project?

Tags: react-native, expo

How would you like to eject your app?

> Bare: I'd like a bare React Native project.
>     ExpoKit: I'll create or log in with an Expo account to use React Native and the Expo SDK.
>     Cancel: I'll continue with my current project structure.

What is the difference between ExpoKit and Bare?

What are the advantage and disadvantage on choosing this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The two ways to use `Expo` tools are called the "managed" and "bare" workflows.

#### Managed workflow

Apps are built with the managed workflow using the `expo-cli`, the Expo client on your mobile device, and `expo` various services: `push notifications`, the `build service`, and `over-the-air (OTA)` updates. Expo tries to manage as much of the complexity of building apps for you as they can.

#### Bare workflow

This is workflow where you use some of the `Expo` tools in a vanilla `React Native` app. Unlike in the managed workflow where you don't touch the underlying native code directly, in this workflow the developer has complete control, along with the complexity that comes with that.

#### ExpoKit

`ExpoKit` is another way to use `Expo` tools in a vanilla `React Native` app. The problem with `ExpoKit` is it is, compared to the "bare workflow", very monolithic — you essentially include the entire runtime from the Expo "managed workflow" in your app, rather than only the pieces of it that you want